# Shuffling List<Button> loses connection to mainpage.xaml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My app creates a list of 20 Buttons that are placed on mainpage.xaml:

```
private List<Button> CreateList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
        {
            string name = string.Format("button{0}", i+1);

            Button buttt = new Button();
            buttt.Name = name;
            buttt.Content = i + 1;
            buttt.Height = 72;
            buttt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            buttt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            buttt.Width = 88;
            buttt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.button_Click);
            GameGrid.Children.Add(buttt);

            myList.Insert(i, buttt);
        }
```

Now if I try to shuffle this list, it seems to lose its connection to the actual buttons on the page.

```
private void Shuffle(List<Button> list)
    {
        //list[1].Content = "DING!";

        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rand.Next(n + 1);
            Button value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
```

Note that if i un-comment `//list[1].Content = "DING!";` and comment out the rest of this method the button's content IS changed on the screen. So I'd assume the link is broken during the shuffle.

So my problem is that when I run this code, the buttons are displayed but are still in order from 1 to 20, instead of being shuffled randomly like I've intended.

Thanks for the help!

***Edit: Here is the full code with Chris's suggestions:***

```
private List<Button> CreateList(List<Marginz> myMargin)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
        {
            string name = string.Format("button{0}", i+1);

            Button buttt = new Button();
            buttt.Name = name;
            buttt.Content = i + 1;
            buttt.Height = 72;
            buttt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            buttt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            buttt.Width = 88;
            buttt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.button_Click);
            Thickness myThickness = new Thickness();
            myThickness.Left = myMargin[i].left;
            myThickness.Top = myMargin[i].top;
            myThickness.Right = myMargin[i].right;
            myThickness.Bottom = myMargin[1].bottom;
            buttt.Margin = myThickness;
            //GameGrid.Children.Add(buttt);

            myList.Insert(i, buttt);
        }

        return myList;
    }
```

And here is where it's called:

```
private void EasyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DifficultyCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        ReadyCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        //set difficulty attributes
        difficulty = "Easy";

        var myMarg = CreateMarginList(marg);
        var buttons = CreateList(myMarg);
        Shuffle(buttons);

        foreach (var button in buttons)
        {
            GameGrid.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

**Edit for more explanation:**
About the Margins. I've created a class called Marginz:

```
public class Marginz
    {
        public Marginz()
        {
            //Constructor
        }
        public int left { get; set; }
        public int top { get; set; }
        public int right { get; set; }
        public int bottom { get; set; }
    }
```

"marg" is a List of this type:

```
List<Marginz> marg = new List<Marginz>(20);
```

And CreateMarginList() does this:

```
public List<Marginz> CreateMarginList(List<Marginz> myMarg)
    {
        Marginz one = new Marginz();
        one.left = 28;
        one.top = 186;
        one.right = 0;
        one.bottom = 0;
        myMarg.Insert(0, one);

        Marginz two = new Marginz();
        two.left = 133;
        two.top = 186;
        two.right = 0;
        two.bottom = 0;
        myMarg.Insert(1, two);
```

etc all the way to twenty. Then `return myMarg;`
So every Button has a unique margin placing it in the Grid.

[image: This is what I have right now:]

Comment: Shuffling the `myList` collection won't change the order they appear on the page. That is determined by the order you add them to the GameGrid in your `CreateList` method. EDIT: What you can do instead is create them all, shuffle the list, _then_ add them to the Children listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You're putting the buttons in a grid, and positioning them with the margin. Since you're using the margin to position them, their position won't change no matter in which order you add them to the grid.

A few ways to do what you're trying to do:

- Apply the margin **after** the button list has been shuffled
- Use a Stackpanel instead of a grid (and remove the margin)
- Use the grid as it's intended to be: create some rows, and assign each button to a row

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinition />
          <Grid.RowDefinition />
          <Grid.RowDefinition />
          etc...
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid>
  ```

  Then in the code behind, set the row of each button:

  ```
  Grid.SetRow(myButton, 1);
  ```

Comment: I did your first suggestion (apply the margin after the button list was shuffled) by using an ApplyMargins() method that I created. This works best for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling the myList collection won't change the order they appear on the page. That is determined by the order you add them to the GameGrid in your CreateList method. What you can do instead is create them all, shuffle the list, *then* add them to the Children listing.

So remove the `GameGrid.Children.Add` call in `CreateList` (note, I kinda tweaked the code there, I'm assuming you weren't posting full code)

```
private List<Button> CreateList()
{
    var myList = new List<Button>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
    {
        string name = string.Format("button{0}", i+1);

        Button buttt = new Button();
        buttt.Name = name;
        buttt.Content = i + 1;
        buttt.Height = 72;
        buttt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        buttt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        buttt.Width = 88;
        buttt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.button_Click);

        myList.Add(buttt);
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Perform your shuffle, then add them:

```
var buttons = CreateList();
Shuffle(buttons);

foreach(var button in buttons)
{
    GameGrid.Children.Add(button);
}
```

EDIT: From your full code that you posted, the problem is that because all of the buttons are in a `Grid` control, their positioning is dictated by which row/column their in *and* their `Margin` (which controls their positioning within that cell). If you do not explicitly define their row/column, which you do not, then they're assumed to be in the first row/column. In this case, their margins, which are not shuffled, dictate their positioning.

I think in this case, either build the Grid with cells, or probably most easily: simply shuffle the `myMargin` list instead before creating the list! The buttons will be added in order, but they'll be given random positions.

```
var myMargin = CreateMargins(); //wherever that's done
Shuffle(myMargin); //you'll have to change the signature to work against List<Thickness> instead
var buttons = CreateList(myMargin); //add back the GameGrid.Children.Add call
//notice, no longer a call to shuffle the buttons
```

Might not be the *best* solution, but I think this will give you the same effect you were going for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What you said makes a lot of sense! But for some reason it still isn't working. The buttons are still displayed in order from 1 to 20 on the screen?

Comment: @davekats Can you set a breakpoint in the debugger and make sure that `myList` is shuffled (check their `Content`) before adding to the GameGrid? Also, did you _remove_ the `GameGrid.Children.Add` call within `CreateList`?

Comment: Yeah I have done both of these things. The Button in myList[1] has a content value of 5, and I commented out the GameGrid.Children.Add call within CreateList.

Comment: Can you post the actual full code of `CreateList` then? Also, what class is `GameGrid`?

Comment: I posted the full code, and GameGrid is a System.Windows.Controls.Grid that is created on the mainpage.xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

You could just shuffle the index of the buttons in the `UIElementCollection`, But you may have to switch grid types as setting all the Margins explicity in your code will not allow it to shuffle.

Are you able to Use `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid` to layout your controls ??

Example based on `UniformGrid` (same will work for all grids unless you have set Margins on the controls).

I know its not an answer to you current question but it may point you in the right direction.

```
private void Shuffle(UIElementCollection list)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rand.Next(n + 1);
        Button value = list.OfType<Button>().ElementAt(n);
        list.Remove(value);
        list.Insert(k, value);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="199" Width="206" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <UniformGrid Name="GameGrid" Margin="0,48,0,0" Height="112" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Content="Button 1" />
            <Button Content="Button 2" />
            <Button Content="Button 3" />
            <Button Content="Button 4" />
            <Button Content="Button 5" />
        </UniformGrid>
        <Button Content="Shuffle" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Shuffle(GameGrid.Children);
    }

    private void Shuffle(UIElementCollection list)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rand.Next(n + 1);
            Button value = list.OfType<Button>().ElementAt(n);
            list.Remove(value);
            list.Insert(k, value);
        }
    }
}
```